# Google Maps Data Layer: loading a second file using map.data.loadGeoJson much slower

Tags: google-maps

I am writing an application that displays zipcode, and other layers on a google map. For the zipcodes I have a simplified geojson file for the upper zoom levels and a more detailed database of features that get added when zoomed in. This works fine on the first load. The map loads at a high zoom level and loads the simplified geojson in ~10 second. However after I zoom in then zoom back out the reload of the simplified geojson takes ~30 second. This is after clearing all previous data with

```
map.data.forEach(function(feature) {map.data.remove(feature); });
```

At first I believed this to be a memory leak issue cause by something else in my code, so I did a simple test where I created a map that just loaded the simplified file, cleared it then loaded it again, and I get the same result of about 3 times load time. I then created a much smaller geojson file with just 3 zipcode boundaries, and did a test where I loaded that tiny file, cleared it then loaded the simplified file and the load takes almost as long ~30 seconds. So it would seem that the simple act of loading a second file causes some sort of extra processing need within Google maps. I have even tried loading the new file in a new layer with

```
high_zoom_zips = new google.maps.Data({map: map})
high_zoom_zips.loadGeoJson('zips.json');
```

however the longer load time remains. Reloading it a third or forth time do not seems to increase the load time significantly

Has anyone else run into this problem? is there a need to reset anything else within Google maps to prevent this extra processing?

Comment: Maybe that's because you loop for `deleting former data` cause some time.

Comment: That is not the reason. I added buttons to trigger the actions and it does not matter how long I wait after the delete the next load still takes much longer